# Invalid procedure call or argument with DateAdd VBA MSACCESS

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Attempt creating a function that would add 100 years to improperly stored dates to correct them , ie 5/10/2016 is stored 5/10/1916 and needs to be converted to 5/10/2016. The function I wrote fails at the line with DateAdd in it.

```
Function CORRECTDATE(INPUTDATE As Date) As Date

    If IsDate(INPUTDATE) Then

        If INPUTDATE >= #1/1/1900# Then
          CORRECTDATE = DateAdd(yyyy, 100, INPUTDATE)
        Else
          CORRECTDATE = INPUTDATE
        End If

    Else
        CORRECTDATE = Null
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Also, your code is not safe as it doesn't check for upper boundary. It will keep adding +100 years every time you run it, as every `INPUTDATE` is past 1 Jan 1900.

Comment: Saw that as soon as I got the right output, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need quotation marks around `yyyy`:

```
CORRECTDATE = DateAdd("yyyy", 100, INPUTDATE)
```

Comment: Thank you , that was as clear as day in the docs , but I guess I am too deep in the forest this morning :)